# Can I name a VeraCrypt volume on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, mount-point, veracrypt

When Veracrypt 1.23 mounts a volume it is name NO NAME. 
Is there a way to give these volumes a name?
I am using the console to create my containers

```
veracrypt -t -c $LOCATION --encryption=AES --hash=SHA-512 --filesystem=FAT --password=$PASSWORD --size=1G --volume-type=Normal --pim=$PIM --keyfiles=
```

I tried renaming the volume in /Volumes/NO\ NAME but that just removes the volume from the desktop.

And specifying a mount point.

```
Enter mount directory [default]: /Users/Test
```

But the volume still mounts as NO NAME

Comment: I am being marked as off-topic for not being a programming question. This line I am looking for is part of a larger script. I just pulled out the feature I am stuck on. There are also Veracrypt questions on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? I wish there was a way to name the volume while creating it.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not

Answer (score 2):

Using diskutil I can rename volumes, as below.

```
/usr/sbin/diskutil rename "NO NAME" "TEST2"
```

I am leaving the question open as this is a bit of a hack.